# NGINX / fascgi-mono-server4 - Multiple sites

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
# Sample site
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4

        server_name  web;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/web.access.log;

        location / {
                root   /srv/www/web/;
                index  default.cshtml Default.cshtml;
                fastcgi_index Default.cshtml;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}

# Another Sample site
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4

        server_name  irws;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/irws.access.log;

        location / {
                root   /srv/www/irws/;
                index  default.cshtml Default.cshtml;
                fastcgi_index Default.cshtml;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Here is my script that starts `fastcgi-mono-server4`:

```
export MONO_IOMAP=all  
fastcgi-mono-server4 /address=127.0.0.1 /applications=irws:/:/srv/www/irws/,web:/:/var/www/web/ /socket=tcp:9000 &
```

I can't figure out why only the first app defined in the `/applications` parameter works. In this case, only `http://irws/` works, but `http://web/` does not. If I switch them to:

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 /address=127.0.0.1 /applications=web:/:/srv/www/web/,irws:/:/var/www/irws/ /socket=tcp:9000 &
```

Then only `http://web/` works and `http://irws` stops working. I think I'm missing something pretty simple here.

The error message I get looks like this:

```
Directory does not exists Parameter name: value

Description: HTTP 400. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.ArgumentException: Directory does not exists
Parameter name: value
  at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_Path (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileSystemWatcher:set_Path (string)
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.SetupOfflineWatch () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.Process (System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest req) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.RealProcessRequest (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest.ProcessRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--applications` parameter specifies paths within the same virtual host. You probably need to write a [webapp file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/fastcgi-mono-server.1.html#contenttoc6) and specify it with the `--appconfigfile` parameter in order to serve multiple virtual hosts.

Comment: Sorry for my noobiness. I scanned through the map page but I can't figure it out by myself. Can you help? I imagine I need to create two webapp files (irws.webapp & web.webapp), but I can't figure out how to construct the fastcgi command.

Comment: Figured it out with help of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12188358/99373